# My app won't run... because of an unchanged AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift

My app was working perfectly until I added an `@IBAction`. Now I just get this error:

> 2017-06-09 07:55:35.285 Press[1594:102051] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key add.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010724bb0b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001044f3141 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010724ba59 -[NSException raise] + 9
>       3   Foundation                          0x0000000104008e8b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
>       4   UIKit                               0x0000000104b60644 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
>       5   UIKit                               0x0000000104dcd6b9 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
>       6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071f1e8d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 269
>       7   UIKit                               0x0000000104dcc06f -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
>       8   UIKit                               0x0000000104b66c73 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
>       9   UIKit                               0x0000000104b67589 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000104b678ba -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000104b6810a -[UIViewController view] + 27
>       12  UIKit                               0x0000000104a3063a -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 65
>       13  UIKit                               0x0000000104a30d20 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294
>       14  UIKit                               0x0000000104a43b6e -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
>       15  UIKit                               0x00000001049bd31f -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4346
>       16  UIKit                               0x00000001049c3584 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1709
>       17  UIKit                               0x00000001049c0793 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 182
>       18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010895b5f6 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24
>       19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010895b46d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 186
>       20  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010895b7f6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071f1c01 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071d70cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
>       23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071d65ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
>       24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071d6016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
>       25  UIKit                               0x00000001049bf02f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
>       26  UIKit                               0x00000001049c50d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       27  Press                               0x0000000103f1a877 main + 55
>       28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001081eb65d start + 1
>       29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

This is my Viewcontroller code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// OUTLETS

@IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    add()
}

// VARIABLES

var scoreVar = 0
let levelUpAt = [50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000]
var currentLevel = 1
var toAdd = 1

// OVERRIDES

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

// FUNCTIONS

// Below code adds to the score

func add() {
    scoreVar += 1 // Adds 1 to scoreVar
    score.text = "scoreVar"; // Updates text to match
    checkForLevelUp(); // Calls the function defined in the next few days ago
}

// Below code checks if the score meets the next level requirements

func checkForLevelUp() {
    if (scoreVar - 1 < levelUpAt[currentLevel - 1]) { // Complicated math-y if statment
        currentLevel += 1
        toAdd += 1
    }
}
```

}

It seems to be stuck on the `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {` line on the AppDelegate, according to the debugger.

Comment: Check your Outlet on your storyboard, they are probably missing.

Comment: yes seems outlet of your button not setted properly.if you modified the method name or param then probably have to remove old outlet also in view

Comment: I tried changing it to `@IBAction func add(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        add()
    }` and no change. Any suggestions on how to connect properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your story board and click on the ViewController. Click one the Add button you created.

[image: Add Button]

On the right side in the Outlet Inspector, remove anything mentioning the "Add" button.

[image: Outlets to remove]

Finally, recreate the outlets by option dragging from the button to your view controller and setting the type to "Action".

[image: New outlet to create]

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I forgot to remove one of the outlets.